# Json string to Xml

Tags: c#, json, xml

I'm a new programmer and I'm really stuck (likely being so new and having so little knowledge) I need to convert a json string (something like this):

```
[
  {
    "Start": "date",
    "Finish": "date",
    "Subject": "",
    "Comments": "",
    "Site": "address",
    "Location": null,
    "Status": false,
    "Arrived": true,
    "Noshow": false,
    "Services": "Initial Consultation",
    "Attendees": [
      {
        "AccountId": 1111,
        "AccountType": "MP",
        "Name": "MMS (FP), Support "
      },
      {
        "AccountId": 2220915,
        "AccountType": "PA",
        "Name": "Test, Patient "
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

into XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <root>
   <element>
      <Arrived>true</Arrived>
      <Attendees>
         <element>
            <AccountId>1111</AccountId>
            <AccountType>MP</AccountType>
            <Name>MMS(FP), Support</Name>
         </element>
         <element>
            <AccountId>2220915</AccountId>
            <AccountType>PA</AccountType>
            <Name>Test, Patient</Name>
         </element>
      </Attendees>
      <Comments />
      <Finish>date</Finish>
      <Location null="true" />
      <Noshow>false</Noshow>
      <Services>Initial Consultation</Services>
      <Site>address</Site>
      <Start>date</Start>
      <Status>false</Status>
      <Subject />
   </element>
</root>`
```

And have tried Googling various answers to no avail. I've tried lots of permutations of **JsonConvert.DecryptXmlNode(filename);** but these all through up errors.
The errors I've had include "Data at root level is invalid." and "Can only convert json that begins with a valid object".

For the purposes of clarification, I've been sent hundreds of Json files (no idea what is in them) and need a sort of 'catch all' scenario.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if the xml is not encrypted you cannot decrypt.  That is why you are getting the errors.

Comment: Use JSON.Net : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm

Comment: I use Newtonsoft's.  It works well.

Comment: There are many libraries that convert JSON to XML but they rarely produce exactly the XML that you want. Usually it's necessary to follow the conversion with a custom transformation (for example in XSLT) that maps the XML into the desired form. That's easy enough for one JSON file, but doing it for hundreds of JSON files when you have no idea what's in them is not going to be easy; you need a clearer picture of how the XML you are producing is going to be used, and what the expectations of the consumers are.

Comment: The JSON is valid. It's an array. That's why the xml uses `<element>` elements to hold values both near the root and in the `attendees`

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
// Calling your JSON deserialization to create an array of dictionarys
var items = json.FromJson<Dictionary<string, object>[]>();
var xml = new XElement("root", 
                            items
                                .Select(it => new XElement("element", 
                                                    it.Select(el => ToXml(el.Key, el.Value)))));    

// method to create xml from a key value pair
XElement ToXml(string key, object item)
{
    if(item is JArray data){
        var items = data.ToString()
                        .FromJson<Dictionary<string, object>[]>();
        return new XElement(key, items.Select(dt => items
                                                    .Select(it => new XElement("element",
                                                            it.Select(el => ToXml(el.Key, el.Value))))));
    }
    return new XElement(key, item);
}

// In a separate class
public static class Extensions
{
    // This uses NewtonSoft.Json for deserialization
    public static T FromJson<T>(this string json)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
        using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jr);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, I recommend validating your JSON using https://jsonlint.com/. 
The outer square brackets are not necessary, and the trailing comma at the end should ideally be removed.

Now, since you mentioned you are using C# and Newtonsoft Json.NET, you could try this in a console program's Program.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq; //For the XDocument class
using Newtonsoft.Json; //For JsonConvert class
using System.IO; //For File class

class JsonToXMLProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myJSONString = @File.ReadAllText(@"H:\MyJsonFile.json"); //Replace with your json files' locations.

        //This converts the JSON string to xml
        XDocument myXMLDocument = JsonToXML(myJSONString);

        //you could then check your xml by outputting it to the console...
        Console.WriteLine(myXMLDocument.ToString());
        //..or by saving the file to disk
        string myXMLFilePath = @"H:\MyXmlDocument.xml"; //Replace with the path to your generated xml files.
        myXMLDocument.Save(myXMLFilePath);
    }


    public static XDocument JsonToXML(string jsonString)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc;
        try
        {
            xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonString, "Root", true);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
        catch (JsonException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There appears to be an error in the json file. Please validate the json to ensure that it is free from errors.");
            Console.WriteLine("Details: " + e.Message);
            return new XDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The outer square brackets are pointless but perfectly legal. The comma on the penultimate line is illegal, but accepted by many JSON parsers.

Comment: @MichaelKay updated the answer to reflect this, thanks.